# Speech Recognition on iPhone

Tags: iphone, speech-recognition

I need to develop an iPhone application which recognizes speech, and based on the result it performs further tasks.

I know iPhone 3.0 doesn't support speech recognition and I need to implement speech recognition software on the server side. I know this thing only, since I am newbie I don't know how to deal with that.

Mean Which software i need to buy and implement it at server side, and how to use that Service ??

Comment: what do you mean server-side?

Comment: He means "not on the phone". It might help to specify if there's a particular server OS you have to use though.

Comment: Server-side means send the audio data to a server, recognize the speech there (using lots of resources and memory) and send the resulting text output back to the phone. Google does that with OCR and machine translation on the Android, for example: Take a pic of some foreign text, it sends it to the server, OCRs and translates it into English and sends the text result back.

Answer (score 7):

The best open source speech recognition package I know of is Sphinx.
http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/

Otherwise, I would suggest looking into Nuance software.

Current speech recognition does well with a limited grammar set (if you know what they are going to say). Open dictation still doesn't quite work well enough to be used reliably for many applications. Keep that in mind while developing your application. I'm hoping now that Google is getting into the transcription game (with Google Voice) that should start improving. I'm thinking they will probably have something in the future.

Comment: [poketsphinx](https://cmusphinx.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/cmusphinx/branches/pocketsphinx-0.6/pocketsphinx/)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there are many server side speech recognition software suites. Open source versions seem virtually non-existent. You might want to take a look at this SDK though:

http://www.scribd.com/doc/17247334/Creaceed-Releases-iPhone-Speech-Recognition-SDK
http://www.creaceed.com/weblog/ceedvocalsdk.html

It might allow you to do what you want on the iPhone itself.

Answer (score 1):

Getting speech recognition right is very tricky and an active research area.

There are a few open-source solutions out there, though, see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speech_recognition_in_Linux). An additional, new one is [SCARF](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/gzweig/), but I don't know if that is ready to use or rather just a proof of concept.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Nuance Mobile Developer program](http://www.nuancemobiledeveloper.com/public/index.php?task=home). We've got libraries for various platforms (including iOS) and an HTTP service if necessary.