# How to convert speech to text in iphone?

Tags: iphone, speech-to-text

I want to build an application where user when talks something on iphone it will convert into corresponding text.

I heard in windows platform it is possible.

Wheather this is possible in iphone ? Any API available for this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question has been asked a lot of times here already, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1118400/speech-recognition) being one of these questions that received quite a few answers and good ideas.

There is no API for doing speech to text on the iPhone, but you can record the voice on the phone, send the recording to a server that runs the speech recognition software on Windows or whatever OS suits you best, then return the text results back to the phone.

Answer (score 2):

I used Nuance’s Dragon Speech SDK for this purpose.

Its free for developers and their SDK have a sample project for STT and TTS both.

Tried Speech to text using this SDK on iOS 9 and it works like a charm.

Here is the link.

https://developer.nuance.com/public/Help/DragonMobileSDKReference_iOS/SpeechKit_Guide/RecognizingSpeech.html

Limitations:

1. 60 seconds recording time limit.
2. Recorded audio file is not accessible.
3. Pauses taken are detected as end of recording.

Answer (score 1):

There's an app for that.

Search for "Dragon Speech".

Answer (score 0):

It is possible on the iPhone. Pocketsphinx has been ported.  For example, an app  called cactus dialer uses pocketsphinx.  No API has been published but its not hard to get it built. Many people have.

For full blown dictation it will be hard. You will need to make it server based like Nuance's 'dragon speech' does or accept a smaller vocabulary.