# how to convert speech to text iPhone?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, speech-to-text

I want to convert speech to text.My problem is that i am working on an application user needs to fill his profile on the basis of what he speech.

Is there any lib/tool with which i can convert sppech to text.
Please suggest me there any tool is available.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert speech to text in iphone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1927493/how-to-convert-speech-to-text-in-iphone)

Answer (score 2):

Unless you use the built in keyboard function that does it then it will be very hard to do.

Even Apple pushes the sound recording to its servers for the servers to process and then return the text.

You might be able to find an online service that does a similar thing.

There are a couple of APIs suggested in this SO question.

[Web services for converting audio speech to text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3774867/web-services-for-converting-audio-speech-to-text)