# I'm trying to program a unique app, and use voice command to trigger specific functions within the app

Tags: iphone, command, voice

If anyone can help me with this, I'd be eternally in their debt.

Without getting bogged down in details, I'm trying to program an app so 
that, for instance, while the application is currently launched, if I say the words, 
"activate function A", a specific function which already exists in my app, is activated.

Have I explained myself clearly? In other words, on the screen of the phone is a button
which says "function A". When the software is "armed" and in listening mode, I want
the user to have the ability to simply say the words "activate function A", 
(or any other phrase of my choice) and the screen option will be selected without requiring
the user to press the button with their hand, but rather, the option is selected/activated 
via voice command.

My programmers and I have faced difficulties incorporating this new voice command capability,
even though it is obviously possible to do google searches with voice command, for instance.
Other voice command apps are currently in circulation, such as SMS dictation apps,
email writing apps, etc, so it is clearly possible to create voice command apps. 
Does anyone know if this is possible, and if so, do you have advice on how to implement
this function?

QUESTION 2

Assuming that we are unable to activate function A via voice command, is it possible
to use voice command to cause the phone to place a call, and this call is received
by our server? The server then 'pings' the iPhone and instructs it to activate function A?
For this workaround to work, I would need the ability to determine the exact phrase.
In other words, the user can't be forced to use the word "call function A". I need the 
ability to select the phrase which launches the function.
Hopefully I've been clear.

In other words, as a potential workaround to the obstacles we've been facing regarding
using voice command to activate a specific function within our app, is it possible
to harness the voice command capability already present in the phone? aka, to place
a phone call? And then this call is received by our server, and the server
accordingly pings the phone which placed the call, and instructs it to activate the function?

I obviously understand the necessity for the app to be currently launched, before it
would be possible for my application to receive the instruction from the server.

If someone can help me to solve this vexing problem, it is not hyperbole to say that
you would change my life!

Thanks so much in advance for any help one of you kind souls can provide!!!

Michael

Comment: I had to read 2 paras to know that this question is about phone... another 2 more to know that its for iphone....

Comment: This looks to be a duplicate of these questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1121548/iphone-speech-recognition-api , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1118400/speech-recognition

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe the iPhone comes with any built in speech recognition functions.  Consider speaking to Nuance about buying and embedding one of their speech recognition engines. They have DragonDictate for iPhone, but they also provide a fair amount of other recognition engines that serve different functions.  Embedded solutions is clearly one of their areas of expertise.

Your other path of pushing the audio to your server may be more involved than you expect.  Typically this process involves end-pointing (when is speech present) and identification of basic characteristics so the raw stream doesn't need to be passed.  Again, investigation into the speech recognition engine you intend to use may provide you with the data processing details you need.  Passing continuous, raw voice from all phones to your servers is probably not going to be practical.

Comment: Nah, iPhone 3GS has speech recognition, except there isn't a public API.