# How Speech to Text conversion in iPhone

Tags: iphone, sdk, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

Is there any way, by which we can convert speech to Text using iPhone SDK?

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/942312/iphone-app-add-voice-recognition and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1118400/speech-recognition, among others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if you are [Google](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/google-mobile-app/id284815942?mt=8), [Dragon](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/dragon-dictation/id341446764?mt=8), or [Siri](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/siri-assistant/id351778157?mt=8). The iPhone SDK does not provide any access to the iPhone 3GS's built-in voice recognition, which is apparently [none too elaborate](http://arstechnica.com/apple/guides/2010/02/iphone-voiceservices-looking-under-the-hood.ars) anyway. Your best bet is to find a web service to which you can upload audio clips for analysis.

Comment: Thank you Noah. Is that the same case for Text to speech?

Comment: Yes. The article I linked to ("none too elaborate") explains how the speech synthesis API works; it's a little more robust, but is still not part of the public SDK. As such, using it, rather than a web-based text-to-speech service, will get your app rejected for use of a private API.

Answer (score 1):

http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/2010/05/vocalkit-shim-for-speech-recognition-on-iphone/

This looks promising.

Answer (score 1):

**Krishnan** ,This is Reply for your Comment `Is that the same case for Text to speech?`.

No there is Library called `OpenEars` by using this Library you may achieve the `text to Speech` functionality.

**OpenEars**

`OpenEars` is an open-source iOS library` for implementing round-trip English language speech recognition and text-to-speech on the iPhone and iPad.

[You should take a look of this library.](http://www.politepix.com/openears)

Answer (score 0):

As of iOS 10 (not released yet), Apple has their own speech recognition API.

https://developer.apple.com/reference/speech/sfspeechrecognizer