# Speech to text conversion in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, speech-recognition

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How Speech to Text conversion in iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2270655/how-speech-to-text-conversion-in-iphone)

In my application I want to record a speech and convert it into text if required.  Is the iPhone able to convert speech into text?  Is there any sample code or tutorial availablle which shows how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

OpenEars is an open-source library for speech to text conversion for iPhone and iPad. You should be able to integrate this into your app. Their website has tutorials for setting up/configuring OpenEars and how to integrate OpenEars into your own iPhone/iPad application.

http://www.politepix.com/openears

Comment: Hi KLibby, I was just wondering if openEars can perform STT on a recorded sample of voice? I looked on their website, but no luck. Many thanks