# Can we use SIRI as a speech to text in our app?

Tags: iphone

I am going to design an App for iPhone 4s where user will have Speech to text feature.

When user taps on UITextView, keyboard will open with microphone option on the left of SpaceKey.

Now my question is, Can I use that microphone option as text input for textview using speech.
I dont have iPhone 4s yet, that why, I can not test it own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Speech to text (i.e. the microphone next to the space bar) is a system-level keyboard feature. Any text field that uses the standard keyboard can use speech to text.

Comment: Text to speech? I think you have mistakenly mentioned "Speech to text" with "text to speech". I am right?

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, there is no SIRI API available to developers yet (though there are quite a few asking for it).

Comment: Yes, I know that there is no API. But microphone option is always there on Keyboard for our apps also (If I am not wrong). Then whats the use of that microphone in our apps if we can not use this as a speech to text translator.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the `OpenEars` for such purpose.

`OpenEars` is an open-source iOS library for implementing round-trip English language speech recognition and text-to-speech on the iPhone and iPad.

[take a look of this link.](http://www.politepix.com/openears)

[Has good discussion regarding this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2270655/how-speech-to-text-conversion-in-iphone)