# iOS - Speech to text, dictation

Tags: ios, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

I have to develop an app which allows user to speech text, but there are some APIs in the iOS SDK which allow that? Or even third part libs? I have only one problem : the app is in italian language, so a third part lib has to support italian language.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2270655/how-speech-to-text-conversion-in-iphone , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4151812/api-or-sdk-for-speech-to-textspeech-recognition-iphone

Comment: and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/942312/iphone-app-add-voice-recognition too

Answer (score 2):

As of iOS 10 (which isn't released at the time of writing), there is a new speech recognition API. It supports over 50 languages and dialects.

If you are looking for a solution, I'd strongly recommend this over a third party library... Apple will keep it up to date, support it, and improve it. You have none of those guarantees with a third party library.

https://developer.apple.com/reference/speech/sfspeechrecognizer

Comment: Great! For sure the use of Apple libraries is a better solution!

Answer (score 1):

Any UITextField or UITextArea can be dictated using the built-in dictation feature (in devices that support it of course).

An API is not available and you cannot use Siri directly for that.

Comment: And there is a way to programmatically "tap" on the microphone button of the keyboard?

Comment: No there is no way doing it without using private apis.

Answer (score 0):

As of this post there is no way of doing this using native iOS SDK. However, you have the IBM Bluemix Speech-to-Text service available to you for free:
http://www.ibm.com/smarterplanet/us/en/ibmwatson/developercloud/speech-to-text.html

Comment: As of iOS 10 there will be.