# voice recognition in iPhone

Tags: iphone, voice-recognition

Is the voice recogniiton a part of iPhone Audio?
I want to build a sample code on voice recognition for iPhone. How to get started? please give me some idea. any documents in iPhone app developers which says about voice recognition programming?

Thank you,

Comment: possible duplicate of [Speech Recognition.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1118400/speech-recognition)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no native voice recognition libraries/API accessible from the iPhone SDK that I know of.  However, you could try looking into some third-party API's such as [CMU Sphinx](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/) or [Sensory](http://www.sensoryinc.com/company/pr09_02.html)

See [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1121548/iphone-speech-recognition-api) for more information.

Comment: NSSpeechRecognizer is not available on iOS.

Comment: @Noah thanks; I just stumbled onto that page and wanted to give a heads-up just in case.  but thank you for confirming it away