# How to successfully import Appkit Framework in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, speech-recognition, appkit

I would to use the NSSpeechRecognition but this Appkit Framework was not available in iPhone os frameworks.

This is available in systems/library/frameworks/Appkit.framework. Is there other way to make use of AppKit for NSSpeechRecognitio in iPhone?

Thank you.
ZaldzBugz

Comment: possible duplicate of [Speech Recognition.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1118400/speech-recognition)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

App-Kit is not available on the iPhone. It's iOS counterpart is UIKit.

You could try [VocalKit](http://github.com/KingOfBrian/VocalKit) for Speech-Recognition on the iPhone.

Comment: I have tried VocalKit but the conversion to text from speech is not that accurate. You really need to get close to your phone and speak for the device to accurately recognize your speech. But its a good one though.

It uses PokectSphinx, but im trying to understand pockteSphinx and maybe i could help building up the VocalKit SDK.

Thanks :)