#  free speech recognition engines for iOS?

Tags: iphone, speech-recognition

I am looking for some free speech recognition engines to use  in my iphone application... can you suggest any?

Comment: Just a thought - you might want to wait until October 4th when the next iPhone is announced before starting any development on speech recognition stuff. There's a lot of rumors that Apple may be announcing speech recognition hidden in iOS5 - which could potentially come with developer API access if the rumors are true.

Comment: @Jordan these rumors also indicate that Nuance is the partner bringing the voice recognition. Having a look at my answer below might be a good starting point if these rumors are going to be truth.

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone speech recognition API?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1121548/iphone-speech-recognition-api)

Comment: See also [Speech Recognition](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1118400/speech-recognition)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of wrappers of the Sphinx speech recognition engine (http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/) available for iOS

https://github.com/KingOfBrian/VocalKit

Through reading his summary you can see he is actually pointing people towards http://www.politepix.com/openears

Answer (score 4):

Nuance just opened the doors for developers to the **Dragon Mobile SDK** (they are industry-leaders). have a look at [NDEV Mobile](http://dragonmobile.nuancemobiledeveloper.com)

Comment: Did anyone else go through the registration process, click the link on the e-mail only to get taken back to the ' signup now ' page?  (ie I think this is broken)

Comment: I think i experienced the same. Just try to log in with your user credentials and it should work as expected.

Comment: At least the "Silver Service" is: http://dragonmobile.nuancemobiledeveloper.com/public/index.php?task=memberServices

Comment: Nuance is not free, it has a 90 day trial period and then requires you pay tiered pricing