# Speech recognition using Openears framework?

Tags: iphone, ios, speech, openears

Operears: The speech recognition(Speech to text) framework for iPhone(iOS Devices), I have installed openears demo app on my iPhone device, It works well but only for a list of words like GO, CHANGE, MODEL. Can we make speech recognition more generic for a real time speech recognition, that is, not limited to few words. It should be generic.

Openears:
http://www.politepix.com/openears/

Comment: Thanks Sumanth for the reply. I have tried using iSpeech as well but it needs internet connection for speech recognition and my I dont have internet connection on my device. iSpeech uses cloud for recognizing speech. Please reply if I can use iSpeech without internet connection.

Answer (score 3):

You have to use new **Language Model** instead of their default one.

The language model is the vocabulary that you want OpenEars to understand, in a format that its speech recognition engine can understand.

The smaller and better-adapted to your users' real usage cases the language model is, the better the accuracy.

An ideal language model for PocketsphinxController has fewer than 200 words.

You can  dynamically create new language model through the LanguageModelGenerator class.

See the **[Details about LangaugeModelGenerator & Openears Basic concepts here](http://www.politepix.com/openears/#LanguageModelGenerator_Class_Reference)**

**Note:**

Please post the queries regarding Openears only in their [forum](http://www.politepix.com/forums/forum/openearsforum/)

You can see more Speech-To-Text SDK's [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9202583/what-is-the-current-best-speech-recognition-api-for-ios-to-match-few-keywords)