# How to convert Voice to text and display in UITextField in objective c (Online mode)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I'm trying to use voice to text conversion to fill UITextFields (online mode).Please explain.

Comment: Your question might be too broad. Please let us know what you have tried so far.

Comment: Is the one that comes with the system keyboard not good enough?

Comment: possible duplicate of [API or SDK for speech to text(speech recognition ) iphone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4151812/api-or-sdk-for-speech-to-textspeech-recognition-iphone)

Answer (score 0):

### Although this question is a duplicate I'm going to answer this!

I used **Openears** in many cases. It might be difficult to implement but it has a ton of features and is the best API you can possibly find.

Additonally it has the feature of **Text-To-Speech** which allows you to read a string aloud for example.

And the best part of it: it works **offline** too!

[Openears](http://www.politepix.com/openears/)

Here are some other questions asked before, which might help you a little. (Duplicates)

[ios speech to text conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15610703/ios-speech-to-text-conversion)

[iPhone App › Add voice recognition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/942312/iphone-app-add-voice-recognition)

[API or SDK for speech to text(speech recognition ) iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4151812/api-or-sdk-for-speech-to-textspeech-recognition-iphone)

[Speech recognition using Openears framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13757897/speech-recognition-using-openears-framework)