# API for text to speech

Tags: ios, text-to-speech

I was wondering if iPhone has any API that supports Text to Speech feature? I looked around but couldn't find any, so just want to confirm.
This will be great if iPhone have this feature..

Comment: Read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9202583/what-is-the-current-best-speech-recognition-api-for-ios-to-match-few-keywords

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Bhumeshwer katre](https://stackoverflow.com/users/673063/bhumeshwer-katre)'s link to [Speech recognition API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9202583/what-is-the-current-best-speech-recognition-api-for-ios-to-match-few-keywords) is very helpful, but

**OpenEars** has the functionality you are requesting.

From the Introduction:

> English text-to-speech on the iPhone, iPod and iPad
>
> ...
> and it is free to use in an iPhone, iPad or iPod app

It can be found here: http://www.politepix.com/openears/