# How to detect audio transients in iOS

Tags: ios, detection, transient

OK,

let me try and rephrase this:
I'm looking for a method, that takes an audio file as an input, and outputs a list of transients (distinctive peak), based upon a given sensitivity.
The audio is a recording of a spoken phrase of for example 5 words. The method would return a list of numbers (e.g. amount of samples or milliseconds) where the words start. My ultimate goal is to play each word individually.

As suggested in a comment (I really struck some negative chord here) I am NOT asking anyone to write any code for me.

I've been around on this forum a while now, and the community has always been very helpful. The most helpful answers were those that pointed out my rigid way of thinking, offering surprising alternatives or work arounds, based upon their own experiences.

### I guess this topic is just too much of a niche.

Before Edit:
For my iOS app, I need to programmatically cut up a spoken phrase into words for further processing. I know what words to expect, so, I can make some assumptions on where words would start.
However, in any case, a transient detection algorithm/method would be very helpful.

---

Google points me to either commercial products, or highly academic papers that are beyond my brain power.
Luckily, you are much smarter and knowledgeable than me, so you can help and simplify my problems.
Don't let me down!

Comment: I guess I'm committing some capital sin here. Can anyone please explain which?

Comment: Your question is so vague and open ended that you'd have attracted close votes, but a question with a bounty can't be closed, so you get downvotes instead.

Comment: You're essentially asking StackOverflow users to write code for your specific use case on their own time. If you can't figure out those academic papers, hire someone who can.

Comment: You don't provide much enough information in my opinion. My first thought was convolution, but if it doesn't need to be that precise, then just a simple high pass filter to find the words and gaps may be adequate. The negativity may be that it isn't a programming question co much as a signal analysis question and by making it a programming question it comes across as "write my code".

Comment: Also, SO is **not** a forum

Comment: hey girl with pearl earring ... you could *possibly* ask a question like this on the gamedev.com site, where, "general techniques" can be discussed.  Quite simply, this site is for asking about specific bugs in code. This site has nothing to do with "general technique discussion".  So, find the better site to ask your question on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of simple basic ideas you can put to work here.

First, take the input audio and divide into small sized buckets (on the order of 10's on milliseconds). For each bucket compute the power of the samples in it by summing the squares of each sample value.

For example say you had 16 bit samples at 44.1 kHz, in array called s. One second's worth of data would be 44100 samples. A 10 msec bucket size would give you 441 samples per bucket. To compute the power you could do this:

```
float power = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 441; i++) {
  float normalized = (float)s[i] / 32768.0f;
  power = power + (normalized * normalized);
}
```

Once you build an array of power values, you can look at relative changes in power from bucket to bucket to do basic signal detection.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, this is by far the most concrete answer. I will try and put it to work.

Answer (score 2):

Audio analysis is a very complex topic. You could easily detect individual words and slice them apart, but actually identifying them requires a lot of processing and advanced algorythms.

Sadly, there is not much we can tell you besides that there is no way around it. You said you found commercial products and I would suggest going for those. Papers are not always complete enough or right for the language/platform/usecase you want, and often lack details for proper implementation for someone without prior knowledge of the topic.

You may be lucky and find an open source implementation that suits your needs. Here's what a little bit of research returned:

[How to use Speech Recognition inside the iOS SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16812577/2053038)

[free speech recognition engines for iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7596816/free-speech-recognition-engines-for-ios)

You'll quickly see speech recognition is not something you should start from scratch. Choose a library, try it for a little bit and see if it works!